# Find out if no touches were made?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that it is possible to detect a touch on iOS using

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

However, is it possible to find out when a user does not touch?

**EDIT**

I want a method to be executed when the user does not touch the screen for 5 seconds. Is this possible?

I do not have any custom methods that react to touches. I only have the existing methods

```
-touchesBegan
-touchesMoved and
-touchesEnded
```

To be more specific, The user can keep touching the screen as many times as he wants, for how long ever he wants. But, when the user does not touch the screen for more than 5 seconds, then a method `-sampleMethod` needs to be fired.

Comment: If the event is not active then its not being touched. Put a listener on the event.

Comment: Any context to what in the world you are talking about?  It took all my might to not vote down your question.  Someone else did while I was writing this. Typically computer programs respond to input and on ios TOUCH is the input.  You want something to happen all the time and be different when the user is touching and when it's not?  Rewrite your question with more info.

Comment: @badweasel , I actually want to do something when the user does not touch for 5 seconds. Makes more sense now?

Comment: Then put that in your question and i'll answer it.

Comment: We don't know what the rest of your code looks like, and if you have any methods that are being called on a regular basis, like a displayLink type loop... like a drawview.  Unless you have a method that is being called regularly, if you're code is all just reactive to touches, there's no way to do it.  We need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a timer with a 5 second interval and every time you get a touch, restart the timer:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)yourMethod {
    NSLog(@"not touched for 5 seconds");
}
```

Depending on your specific needs, you might want to use `touchesEnded:withEvent` instead.

Comment: Mr @Sebastian , You are a genius. I finally got this working. Wow, thanks. 1000 thanks.

Comment: That would find out if 5 seconds pass after one touch before another touch.  But not if 5 seconds pass after, say, something new is placed on the screen with no touches.  Just saying.  Example.. if the user NEVER touches the screen... this wouldn't work.

Comment: I assumed that the timer is initially schedules somewhere else. This is just a minimal working example.

Comment: @Sebastian , I added the code to `-touchesEnded`. It works fine except when the case where the user keeps touching something (`-touchesMoved`) , and the method still fires. Is there a method to prevent this?

Comment: if `touchesEnded` gets called, there can still be active touches (e.g. 2 touches began, 1 ended). You can get all the touches from the `event` parameter with `event.allTouches`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a whack at an answer here.  Because in the comments you clarified what you're trying to do.  Something after 5 seconds with no response.  What I'm showing here is typically used in opengl apps which all my apps are.  But something like it should work for you even if your not in open gl.

You need something that runs continuously...

```
    - (void) startAnimation
{
    if (!animating)
    {
        displayLink = [NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink") displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(drawView)];
        [displayLink setFrameInterval:animationFrameInterval];
        [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        animating = TRUE;
    }
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    if (animating)
    {
        [displayLink invalidate];
        displayLink = nil;

        animating = FALSE;
    }
}
```

We use this in oepngl apps to run the drawview function every 60th of a second timed with the refresh of the display.  I don't see why you couldn't do it.  Then in you drawView method check the time at the beginning and take care of any other crap you need to, like advancing pieces in a game or just checking to see how long messages have been up..

```
- (void)drawView
{
timeThisRound = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

And check it against whatever event triggers the start of the 5 seconds.  If you're past 5 seconds then do whatever you're going to do instead of waiting any longer for them to tap the button.

I have my own messaging system that does this.  I can set for any message that comes up if it should go away on it's own after 5 seconds.  Or if they tap it, it goes away faster.  I use the timeThisRound method (a global property) everywhere to track when NOW is so that I can have timing based things as well as touch based things.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the rest of the time.  What do you mean?  The only way would be to set a boolean flag to false, and in your "touched" method, set it to true.  Then anytime it's false, there's been no touch...

Answer (score 0):

Launch a method after a certain delay, starting when user stops touching the view.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self performSelector:@selector(sampleMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];
}
```

If user touches the view again, you should cancel the pending method call

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(sampleMethod) object:nil];
}
```

Remember to put a cancel of the pending method call in dealloc too

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(sampleMethod) object:nil];
}
```

Comment: @user2229411 you can use a similar code also with the NSTimer implementation given by Sebastian , just put `[timer invalidate]` in touchesBegan and start the timer in touchesEnded. This solves your problems with touchesMoved.